# how to reduce the code with this enum lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, validation

I have these if-else statements that I am not able to refactor.  I have used them for doing validations on server-side using asp.net.

Would anyone please suggest ways to reduce these statements?  Here, validation fields and validation types are `enum` lists.

```
else if (CheckNextItem(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ValidationFields.FO.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString()))
{
   BrkTypeValidator2.ErrorMessage = "'TOP0618 -Invalid combination of Bracket IDs'";
   args.IsValid = false;
}
else if (CheckNextItem(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ValidationFields.FW.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString()))
{
   BrkTypeValidator2.ErrorMessage = "'TOP0618 -Invalid combination of Bracket IDs'";
   args.IsValid = false;
}
else if (CheckNextItem(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ValidationFields.UF.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString()))
{
     BrkTypeValidator2.ErrorMessage = "'TOP0618 -Invalid combination of Bracket IDs'";
     args.IsValid = false;
}
else if (CheckNextItem(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ValidationTypes.O.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString()))
{
      BrkTypeValidator2.ErrorMessage = "'TOP0618 -Invalid combination of Bracket IDs'";
      args.IsValid = false;
}
else if (CheckNextItem(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ValidationTypes.W.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString()))
{
      BrkTypeValidator2.ErrorMessage = "'TOP0618 -Invalid combination of Bracket IDs'";
      args.IsValid = false;

}
else if (CheckNextItem(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString(), ValidationTypes.C.ToString()))
{
      BrkTypeValidator2.ErrorMessage = "'TOP0618 -Invalid combination of Bracket IDs'";
      args.IsValid = false;

}
else if (CheckNextItem(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ValidationTypes.C.ToString(), ValidationTypes.U.ToString()))
{
      BrkTypeValidator2.ErrorMessage = "'TOP0618 -Invalid combination of Bracket IDs'";
      args.IsValid = false;

}
```

This is method for `Checknextitem`:

```
 public static bool CheckNextItem(string Compareitem1, string comnpareitem2, string items1, string items2)
  {

        var listContains = Compareitem1 == items1 && comnpareitem2 != items2;
        return listContains;

  }
```

if i use this code

```
 var invalidComparisons = new ValidationTypes[][] {
                      new[] { ValidationFields.FO, ValidationTypes.P },
                      new[] { ValidationFields.FW, ValidationTypes.P },
                      new[] { ValidationFields.UF, ValidationTypes.O },
                      new[] { ValidationTypes.O, ValidationTypes.P },
                      new[] { ValidationTypes.W, ValidationTypes.P },
                      new[] { ValidationTypes.P, ValidationTypes.C },
                      new[] { ValidationTypes.C, ValidationTypes.U },
                   };
```

i am getting compile time error : **"No Best Type found for implicitly- typed array"**.

Comment: Use an array and a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list / array to store which validation types to compare:

```
var invalidComparisons = new string[][] {
        new[] { ValidationFields.FO.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString() },
        new[] { ValidationFields.FW.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString() },
        new[] { ValidationFields.UF.ToString(), ValidationTypes.O.ToString() },
        new[] { ValidationTypes.O.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString() },
        new[] { ValidationTypes.W.ToString(), ValidationTypes.P.ToString() },
        new[] { ValidationTypes.P.ToString(), ValidationTypes.C.ToString() },
        new[] { ValidationTypes.C.ToString(), ValidationTypes.U.ToString() },
};

if (invalidComparisons.Any(x => CheckNextItem(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString(), x[0], x[1]))
{
    BrkTypeValidator2.ErrorMessage = "'TOP0618 -Invalid combination of Bracket IDs'";
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: pls see the edited code , i am getting error UF and FW and Fo are comes in different enum list not the same one ....

Comment: @p.s.w.g i think no need to have separate method `CheckNextItem` to validate `if (invalidComparisons.Any(x=>x[0] ==ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() && x[1] == ddlBr2Type.SelectedValue.ToString()))` will do the same

Comment: @Damith True, but it's possible that the `CheckNextItem` function is used elsewhere. Even so, it's a pretty uninteresting method, and I'd probably eliminate it altogether.